# Router navigate immediate execution in async/await method

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, routes

I have **component A** which has **async method abc()**. Inside of this method I'm awaiting of another **async method xyz()** inside **service X**. In this xyz() method, I have another await calls (I need to perform calls in order and use response in next request).  It could happen that in case of negative results in two specific calls, I would like to redirect user to one of two pages (currently let's assume that's only one page). I'm using `router.navigate(['/error'])`, but it's not working as I expected... I would expect that it will stop further execution of the code and will perform immediate redirection.

**x.service.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
   await this.abc();
}

async abc(): Promise<any> {
   await this.serviceX.xyz();

   // below calls are still executed even if we entered the navigation line in xyz() method
   await this.service3.magicMethod();
   await this.service4.anotherMethod();
}
```

**a.component.ts**

```
async xyz(): Promise<any> {
   const result = await this.service1.getData(); // 
   if (result !== 'OK') {
      this.router.navigate(['/error']);
   }

   const userAnswer = await this.service2.userSelection();
   if (userAnswer !== 'OK') {
      this.router.navigate(['/error']);
   }
}
```

Both, service1 and service2 have async functions where I'm awaiting for HTTP response using `toPromise()`. Something like that:

```
async getData(): Promise<SomeResponse> { // or userSelection()
   const response = await this.wrapperService.getHttpResponse().toPromise();
   console.log(response);
   return response as SomeResponse;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"

Comment: You're sure that the results aren't "OK" and never entering your conditionals?

Comment: @KurtHamilton, I've updated my post with this sentence - "I expect that it will stop further execution of the code and will perform immediate redirection." Which is not happening, because as I mentioned in the commented part of code.

Comment: @AdamDunkerley yes I checked that before I posted here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're expecting processing to stop, then you need to tell it to stop. The function `router.navigate` is called in will continue to process unless told otherwise.

In your case it looks like you're performing routing in the service, which is leaking UI concerns into your service layer. I would refactor your service method to return a result indicating success or failure. Your component can then choose to navigate or continue processing.

**service.ts**

```
async xyz(): Promise<boolean> {
   const result = await this.service1.getData(); // 
   if (result !== 'OK') {
       // no further processing
      return false;
   }

   const userAnswer = await this.service2.userSelection();
   if (userAnswer !== 'OK') {
      // no further processing
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

**component.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
   await this.abc();
}

async abc(): Promise<any> {
   const success = await this.serviceX.xyz();
   if (!success) {
     this.router.navigate(['/error']);
     // no further processing
     return;
   }

   await this.service3.magicMethod();
   await this.service4.anotherMethod();
}
```

I've added `return;` statements after your call to `router.navigate` to stop further processing.

If you need to return more information that true/false from your service then you could return either an error message or some kind of object. A boolean is sufficient for explaining the concept though.

EDIT:

Obviously if you *really* wanted to perform routing in the service, there's nothing to stop you doing it there. You would still follow this pattern of returning a success result, except the navigation now happens in the service before each `return false;` statement.

EDIT 2:

As we discussed in the comments, I'm not trying to dictate your design decision here, just suggesting a pattern for how you can solve your problem.

There is more overhead in returning an error result and then mapping that result to a path, but I would still personally prefer that for clarity than mixing routing in with data calls. The phrase spaghetti code comes to mind...

An example of the kind of approach I would take for keeping service calls and routing separated. It's just a demonstration of a pattern rather than production-ready code, but hopefully gives you some ideas. I don't mind a bit more typing in exchange for a cleaner design.

**service.ts**

```
export enum XyzError = { ErrorA = 1, ErrorB = 2 }

async xyz(): Promise<XyzReason> {
   const result = await this.service1.getData(); // 
   if (result !== 'OK') {
       return XyzReason.ErrorA;
   }

   const userAnswer = await this.service2.userSelection();
   if (userAnswer !== 'OK') {
      return XyzReason.ErrorB;
   }

   return null;
}
```

**component.ts**

```
async abc(): Promise<any> {
   const result: XyzReason = await this.serviceX.xyz();
   switch (result)  {
     case XyzReason.ErrorA:
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/errora');
       return;
     case XyzReason.ErrorB:
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/errorb');
       return;
   }

   await this.service3.magicMethod();
   await this.service4.anotherMethod();
}
```

Comment: Well, but do I need to handle this response in my component before performing calls in commented part of code? I tried your solution, but calls in commented line of code are still executed. Let me update the part with commented line of code for better explanation.

Comment: The order of calls is a bit confusing because I think they're mis-labelled. Can you provide a stackblitz

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, your service is doing the routing? If this is the case then I feel this is a bad design choice. I don't think routing should take place in data services, and the services should be refactored to return some kind of result indicating failure or success

Comment: I will try to provide it later. Now I can say that first we call `abc()`, then `xyz()` which executes `getData()` or `userSelection()`. In case of KO response I want to perform immediate redirection. Instead of it, `magicMethod()` and `anotherMethod()` are also executed. Which is not what I want. I want to stop on `xyz()` and redirect.

Comment: Correct. I want to perform routing from my service. If it's not good design, how I should provide quite generic solution? Because redirect to error page or my second page, could happen multiple times. And for me it seems ugly to return from all my services a path or something and then handle it in component to perform required routing... What would be the good approach for that?

Comment: I've edited my answer. The service returns a boolean, and the component decides whether to navigate or continue processing. The service only executes for as long as its inner calls are successful.

Comment: So in my case, when I would like to redirect to one of the pages, I should be returning string with page. And still handle the response to perform potential execution. I hoped that it is possible to perform redirection from `not component`, because I have multiple services where navigation is required and services must be called in specific order.

Comment: I've edited my answer to say that you can still perform navigation in the service. You could either: a) navigate in the service and follow the true/false pattern or b) return something indicating what the failure is (I would advise against returning the path if you're keeping routing out of the service - that's not *why* it failed).

Comment: But you said that's bad design choice. I'm not saying it's good, but I don't want to practice bad design... I understand that it was failing, because I didn't stop execution by adding some response to the service and handling it. By returning something what would indicate the failure, I imagine preparing some kind of error codes or something and then handling them in component by mapping them to correct redirection. Tens of if conditions with setting route seems quite ugly and repeating code. With this mapping method its at least hidden. Is prettier solution possible? Something more generic?

Comment: Programming is all about design choices and making compromises. You are in the best place to decide what works best for you. It's easy for me to recommend not performing routing in your service, because we're using trivial examples. Ultimately, the main things that will affect your design decisions: readability, comprehensibility, testability, how it fits in with your app-wide architecture, and how much it follows best practices. I would always prefer a clean design that will scale well, but that's just my preference

Comment: I've added an example of how I would navigate to different routes based on the outcome of the service call. Hopefully that gives you an idea of what I'm on about. However you do it, the original problem of stopping processing after navigation has been answered.

Comment: I totally agree with your statement about programming. About your added example, I was thinking about something similar. Thank you for your help.